# Laravelのバリデーションで配列の添え字が0からの連番かどうか

Tags: laravel

Laravel8で配列の添え字(キー)が0からの連番かどうかをバリデーションしたいのですが、どうやったらよろしいでしょうか。

```
<input name="fruits[0]" >
<input name="fruits[1]" >
<input name="fruits[2]" >
…
```

独自のルール(カスタムバリデーション)を作るという手もありますが、簡単に行う方法があれば知りたいです。
配列や配列の中身のバリデーションは既にできています。

ちなみにこの質問に至った経緯ですが、バリデーション後の配列の添え字は信用できるのかなと思ったわけです。

```
$validated = $request->validated()
// $key は信用できる？
foreach ($validated["fruits"] as $key => $fruit) {
```

(この例の場合信用できないなら自分で0から始まるカウンタを作ればいいだけですが)

追記
確認しましたが送信された配列のキーそのままなので改竄される可能性があり、使わないかバリデーションするかになると思います。

Comment: `<input name="fruits[]"><input name="fruits[]"><input name="fruits[]">` と並べれればlaravel側が0から詰め込んでくれます。fruitsがarrayかをvalidationすればよい気がしますが、添え字を指定することが必須でしょうか？

Comment: 添え字は[0]にしても[]でも大丈夫です。
ただ悪意のあるユーザーによってその添え字が書き換えられて送信されると、laravel側はそのまま受け取ります。
つまりその添え字は何が入っているかはわからないので信用するべきではないと考えました。
validated()で取得したのに信用できない値があるのはおかしいので、バリデートの対象とすることにして簡単な方法はないかなと思ったのです。

Comment: 追記にもありますがキーの連続性を信用しては駄目です。使うべきではないです。バリデーションとはあくまでもユーザ入力に対するデータの型や形式のサポートであり、配列を改竄してくるようなユーザはバリデーションで親切に対応する必要はないかと思います。

Comment: 確かに改竄に対してはメッセージを出すべきではないですよね。
その辺の対処はMessageBagの任意のメッセージを削除できればいいのですが、英語版stackoverflowでもできないということでした。(もちろん今回の場合は「配列の添え字は信用せず使わない」という方法があります)

Comment: 配列がある度にカスタムバリデーションで0から連番チェックするならそもそも配列の添え字を信用しない、つまりそのバリデーションは行わないというのを基本とするほうがシンプルかもしれませんね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

デフォルトでそういったバリデーションは用意されていないのでカスタムバリデーションを書くことになります

FormRequestを使った場合ですが、controllerで書く場合も参考になると思います

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-closures

```php
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'fruits.*' => 'required|integer|min:0',
            'fruits' => [
                'required',
                'min:0',
                'array',
                function($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                    $count = count($value);
                    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
                        if (array_key_exists($i, $value) === false) {
                            $fail("error index {$i} on {$attribute}");
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Comment: このコードかなり勉強になります。ありがとうございます。

Comment: `'fruits.*' => 'required|integer|min:0',` 特に説明なく中身を数字でバリデーションしてますが、好きに改変されてください